# Trying to scrape dynamic content from page I need to scroll element with selenium and get an exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to scroll a menu with this `div` in

```
<div class="N9abW" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden auto;"><div style="flex-direction: column; padding-bottom: 8640px; padding-top: 0px;">

<div style="flex-direction: column; padding-bottom: 8640px; padding-top: 0px;"><div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm   pjcA_                                                      iHqQ7                           L-sTb                          ">
```

My code is this:

```
area =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.N9abW')
time.sleep(5)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
action = ActionChains(driver) 
action.move_to_element(area).click().perform()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1500);", area)
```

I got no error program exit after code. If someone has a clue or tied same thing. Please help.

Comment: I also try with send key DOWN to .N9abW element but same result:selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException

Comment: Also with javescript code driver.execute_script("(arguments[0]).click();", area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", area)
```

could you try the above script

Comment: Its move a little bit but to the last result in the view its not scrolling.

Comment: replace scrollintoview with .scrollTop(0);

Comment: what did you prvide]

Comment: I miss the dot but this is the output: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollTop is not a function
I provide this  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop(0);", area)

Answer (score 0):

```
    area =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.N9abW')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    action = ActionChains(driver) 
    action.move_to_element(area)
    print(area)
    scrol = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,1000)", area)
```

This fix the issue thank to  PDHide

```
"arguments[0[.scrollBy(0,1000)", area)
```